# JDBC Connection Pooling vs Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, dependency-injection, connection-pooling

I'm quite new to Java EE and Connection Pooling. I've already tried few pools and every single one of them had the following issue:

```
ConnectionPoolDataSource source = new ConnectionPoolDataSource(); //Stands for any CP pool object

source.setUser("blabla");
source.setAnything("blabla";
```

As you can see, variable called "source" references to an object with specific type. Eg. for C3PO it is ComboPooledDataSource.

What I want to do is inject objects capable of connection pooling via Spring IOC. So I need some sort of interface. Trouble is, [DataSource interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) only has two methods for getting the actual connection. Simply Using:

```
DataSource source = SomeIocContainer.getObject("DataSource");
```

I can't

```
source.setUser("blabla");
source.setOtherStuff("blabla");
```

Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your application context(xml):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
```

Then you can inject the dataSource in some DAO:

```
@Repository
public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // JDBC-backed implementations of the methods on the CorporateEventDao follow...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to deal with database access credentials in your application code. The `DataSource` is configured with the container, either the Spring `ApplicationContext` or the Java EE application server. Connection pooling is also configured with the container. Start with simple examples from the documentation and carefully extend these.

I suggest you get familiar with concepts of both Spring ([Spring 3 JDBC Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)) and Java EE ([Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/)).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Database Connection Pools generally create connections with all the same properties, hence the  properties being set on the pool. The connections with other properties, use multiple pools.

A simple Spring config for a Connection Pool:

```
<bean id="springDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-  method="close" >
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SPRING_TEST" />
 <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
 <property name="username" value="root" />
 <property name="password" value="root" />
 <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
 <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
 <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
</bean>
```

From: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/jdbc-database-connection-pool-in-spring.html